# Older sci-fi book about passive human-like herd animals vs predatory breeders

Tags: story-identification, books

Older sci-fi book about intelligent herd-like animals.

I read this book many, many years ago. I only remember that it loosely included these elements.

It was an older science fiction book about a man landing on planet finding passive intelligent herd animals, sheep like and savage human like animals breeders. The man gradually has a change in perspective about the value of the two groups.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you be more specific about approximately what year you read this?  How big was this book?  (Something very slim, like an Andre Norton book, or a tome like Robert Jordan wrote?)  Do you remember the cover design?

Comment: Any details about the plot may also be helpful

Comment: Not the answer, but a shout out to the similar scene in Venus on the Half Shell.

Comment: This trope had been done a few times. The grandaddy of them all is Jonathan Swift's journey to the land of the Houyhnhnms from _Gulliver's Travels_.

Comment: You might want to add more details as this trope gets used a lot.  My first thought was that you were talking about The Time Machine, but I imagine you are probably not talking about The Time Machine.

Answer (score 20):

[Mary Doria Russel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Doria_Russell)'s 1996 novel *[The Sparrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sparrow_(novel))* is about humans visiting a habitable planet in the [Alpha Centauri star system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Centauri), and discovering two sentient species: the herbivorous herd-like Runa, and the predatory Jana'ata. There are a few POV characters, but one of the foremost is a Jesuit Priest selected for the mission to Alpha Centauri because of his tremendous language skills. The novel, and its sequel *[Children of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_God_(novel))*, address shifts in perspective that transform perceptions of good and evil, justice and injustice as inherent in the aliens' cultures and biologies.

Comment: +1 For mentioning this lesser known novel. However, on a personal note, this book infuriated me. I expected more scifi (even philosophical scifi) but couldn't digest the fact this novel is 90% jesuit philosophy with a tiny sprinkling of scifi, almost as an excuse. And it takes _forever_ to get there, too. Oh well.

Answer (score 15):

[The Time Machine by H.G. Wells](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2493.The_Time_Machine) has protagonist arrive at Earth in distant future. Humans he sees lost most intelligence - they have language but only concrete nouns etc. Later he discovers other Humans - Morlocks. Morlocks provide services (like making shoes) to sheep-people (Eloi) but eat them.

"The man gradually has a change in perspective about the value of the two groups" part is a bit of a stretch. If I remember correctly then protagonist doesn't criticize Morlocks. In fact I got the feeling that sheep-people got what they deserve for their decadence (they are supposedly descendants of bourgeois class).

Comment: But our hero does fall for an Eloi and tries to defend her, unsuccessfully as it turns out, from the Morlocks. That actually was the impetus for his attempted return to that time, and with that, the accidental loss of him and the Machine in the end.

Comment: Really? I read it long ago but I remember being really unimpressed by his love. It feels like it was half-assed curiosity about a pet that got attached to him. Of course I may remember wrong.

Comment: I can't argue, it was unimpressive. But it also felt like about as much as could be expressed by a book's narrator at the time it was written. But he did say that it was because of her that he was going back then, or at least that's how I remember it.

Answer (score 4):

This makes me think of a short story by Michael Kube-McDowell titled [Slac//](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43097) which has been collected into a book several times. In the story a human scientist is visiting a planet with a primitive pastoral species (who always travel in pairs, with each pair being very dependent on each other); these primitives are threatened by a more aggressive species also native to the planet, and the human gradually realizes that the other species is also sentient, perhaps more advanced than the people he's been embedded with.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say in which direction the narrator's change of perspective went.  A  possible match is [The World Menders](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/516135.The_World_Menders) (1971), by Lloyd Biggle Jr. The summary on Wikipedia does not really emphasize the part of the story that matches your query, but I will quote the end of it for convenience.

> Back at base Farrari soon discovers the mistake he made in believing
> that he could bring freedom to the slaves. He had already noticed that
> the slaves had no culture. Now he understands that the slaves are
> actually little more than animals, comparable, perhaps, to
> Australopithecus or Homo erectus on the human lineage. This is the
> first time that IPR has encountered a sub-human species on the verge
> of achieving sentience, so the scientists at the base and in the field
> intend to study the slaves intensely. Farrari and Liano go back into
> the field themselves, intending to try, ever so gently, to get the
> slaves to develop a simple culture.

In Farrari's revised understanding of things, the "savage human-like animal breeders" are better viewed as a Medieval or Rennaissance level human culture  who happen to share the planet with another humanoid species that may be pre-sentient but has not yet evolved to have a recognizable culture.  They are sometimes "farmed" for use as labor at simple tasks like cultivation.  There are occasional "breeders" who mistreat their stock, but they are the exception rather than the norm.  In the end he recommends that the more evolved race be encouraged to introduce democratic rule rather than autocracy, and the the less evolved race be studied and protected as a future second sentient race (exactly how that would work is never discussed).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [The Word for World Is Forest](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/276767) by Ursula Le Guin. It is about a colonised planet and its non-aggressive natives. And how they deal with the violent and greedy colonisers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *The Web of the Chozen* by Jack L. Chalker?

Comment: If possible, please edit this answer to explain how it matches the OP's description. It'd help other users determine how likely it is to be the correct answer.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this work answers the question. You can find [tips on how to write a good story identification answer and what details to add in our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/7957).

Answer (score -2):

I'm definitely going with "Time Machine." The movie with Guy Pierce left such a memorable impression on me.

Comment: This would be better posted as a comment on [MateuszL's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/284202/122024) rather than as a separate answer in itself. That said, you'd need at least 50 reputation in order to do that.